# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this.contarct.getLastName(...).call is not a function

Tags: solidity, react

I want to get the customers last name but i get the following error any idea how to fix that ?

And is there a way to modify my current get function so that it returns the first name and last name at once ?

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this.contarct.getLastName(...).call is not a function

React:

```
changeLastName(e){
e.preventDefault();
let id = e.target.dataset.somefield;
this.contarct.getLastName(id).call().then((lastName)=>{

this.setState({lastName:lastName});

}
);
}

<form data-somefield={this.id} onSubmit={this.changeLastName}>
<input type="text" name="id"/>
<input type="text"/>
</form>
<p>{this.state.lastName}</p>
```

solidity:

```
struct {
string lastName;

}
getLastName(unit256 _id)public view returns (string){
unit256 id = customersIndex[_id];
return customers[id].lastName;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract to set and get the names:

```
contract mycontract{

    struct userData {
        string lastName;
        string name;
    }


    mapping(uint => userData) private costumers;

    function  setUserData(string _lastname, string _name, uint256 _id) public{
        costumers[_id].lastName = _lastname;
        costumers[_id].name = _name;
    }

    function  getUserData(uint256 _id) public view returns (string, string) {
        return (costumers[_id].lastName,costumers[_id].name);
    }

}
```

using web3 you can get the data like this:

```
ABI = 'the abi of the contract above';
var account = web3.eth.accounts[0]; 
var mycontract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var contractInstance = mycontract.at('contractaddress...')
contractInstance.setuserData('jane','Smith',1, function(err,res){
        if(err){
            console.log('transaction failed')
        } 
    })
```

for getting the user by Id:

```
contractInstance.getUserdata(1, function(err,res){
            if(err){
                console.log('transaction failed')
            } else{
                console.log(res)
            } 
        })
```

`res` will contain the name and the last name.

Hope this helps